# how to make angular 2 "https" request

Tags: http, angular, https, server, client

The server side of my project uses nodejs.
I use https.createServer(option,function(req,res){....}) and it works.

The client side of my project uses angular 2. I know angular 2 has http but I want to make angular 2  use https call to connect server side. I know a solution is use 
this.http .get(https://url). However, I don't know how to use it in  my code.

```js
export class HttpDataService<T> extends DataService<T> {
    protected _url: UrlType;


    constructor(protected http: Http) {
        super();
        this.fetch();
    }

   this.http.get(url)
            .map( (res) => {
                return res.json();
            } )
            .catch( (error: any) => {
                console.log(error);
                this._fetching = false;
                return Observable.throw(error);
            } )
            .subscribe( data => {
                this.setData(data);
                this._fetching = false;

                this._count++;
                if ( (this._count <   
                      this._url.count) ||
                     (this._url.count ==                                  
                      **strong text**UrlTypeCount.Infinite) ) 
                    this.fetch();
            } );


}
```

Comment: Looks like `this.http.get(...)` is outside the constructor. You can't have arbitrary expressions and statements outside of methods in TypeScript. What's the problem with your code? What's not working as expected?

Comment: My code can work by using http. However, I want to use https and I don't know how to use it in angular2 !!@GünterZöchbauer

Comment: So what is not working? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code in a function. Your class body is calling something now, but it shouldn't. For example:

```
export class HttpDataService<T> extends DataService<T> {
    protected _url: UrlType;


    constructor(protected http: Http) {
        super();
        this.fetch();
    }

    getStuff() {
       this.http.get(url)
            .map( (res) => {
                return res.json();
            } )
            .catch( (error: any) => {
                console.log(error);
                this._fetching = false;
                return Observable.throw(error);
            } )
            .subscribe( data => {
                this.setData(data);
                this._fetching = false;

                this._count++;
                if ( (this._count <   
                      this._url.count) ||
                     (this._url.count ==                                  
                      **strong text**UrlTypeCount.Infinite) ) 
                    this.fetch();
            } );
      }
}
```